# How to use hypothesis testing with p-value and level of significance on a linear model correlation?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, correlation, p-value

I am confused about an exercise I found online related to the p-value. The exercise is the following:

*After training a simple linear regression on a dataset with dependent variable y and independent variable x, you want to know whether or not a linear relationship exists between the two variables. You conduct a hypothesis test on the population correlation coefficient ($\rho$), with a level of significance $\alpha=0.5$ and the following hypotheses:*

*$H_0$: $\rho$ is equal to $0$*

*$H_1$: $\rho$ is different from $0$*

*You get a p-value of $0.06$, what conclusion can you draw?*

Possible choices are:

1. There is not enough evidence of a linear relationship between $x$ and $y$ because the correlation coefficient is greater than zero.
2. There is not enough evidence of a linear relationship between $x$ and $y$ because the p-value is greater than zero.
3. There is not enough evidence of a linear relationship between $x$ and $y$ because the p-value is not significantly different from zero.
4. There is not enough evidence of a linear relationship between $x$ and $y$ because the correlation coefficient is not significantly different from zero.

My reasoning is the following. The smaller the p-value the strongest the evidence against the null hypothesis, and if smaller than the chosen $\alpha$, the null hypothesis is rejected. Being this the case, one can conclude $H_1 \ne 0$, hence there is some correlation.

[For linear models correlations are standardised to vary between $-1$ and $+1$, with $0$ representing no relationship, $-1$ a perfect negative relationship, and $+1$ a perfect positive relationship](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Correlation).

Hence the obtained results might mean there is a kind of linear relationship but this seems not to be contemplated among the answers.

Going through the choices:

1. There is not enough evidence of a linear relationship between $x$ and $y$ because the correlation coefficient is greater than zero: **WRONG: being the null hypothesis rejected, the alternative hypothesis is true but it is telling just that the correlation is $\ne 0$**.
2. There is not enough evidence of a linear relationship between $x$ and $y$ because the p-value is greater than zero: **WRONG: representing the p-value a probability, it is always $ 0 \le p-value \le 1$ where $0$ is an ideal case. It is how close to $0$ or how close to $1$ that matters**.
3. There is not enough evidence of a linear relationship between $x$ and $y$ because the p-value is not significantly different from zero: **WRONG: a p-value far from $0$ would mean the null hypothesis is not rejected, i.e. there is not a linear relationship, whereas the closeness to $0$ indicates the linear relationship**.
4. There is not enough evidence of a linear relationship between $x$ and $y$ because the correlation coefficient is not significantly different from zero: **WRONG: as in Q1 the value of the correlation is unknown, it is just known that it is different from $0$**.

So all the answers seem to me to be implausible, but maybe I am getting the wrong concept about something.

Can anyone clarify where I am wrong?

Comment: Did you mean $\alpha=0.05?$

Comment: Let's assume that there is a typo and $\alpha=0.05$. Then the correct answer is the fourth answer. Can you figure out why?

Comment: @Dave Well, that is what I thought, but the in the exercise it is $0.5$.

Comment: $\alpha=0.05$ is such a common choice that it has to be a typo..

Comment: Anyway, if it is $0.05$, basically p-value is bigger than the $\alpha$ hence the null hypothesis is valid, according to which $\rho = 0$.

Comment: I think the phrasing in #4 is pretty good.